# Java 9 exports cycles

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system

In Java 9 cycles between modules are not allowed so A requires B but B can't require A.

However, looking through the JDK code base I can see that `java.management` module  contains  `exports com.sun.jmx.remote.util to java.management.rmi;` and in the `java.management.rmi` module I see exports `com.sun.jmx.remote.protocol.rmi to java.management;`

Why is this cyclic rule relaxed for export statements?

```
module java.management {
    exports javax.management.remote;
    exports javax.management.timer;
    exports sun.management.counter to jdk.management.agent;
    exports com.sun.jmx.remote.util to java.management.rmi;
    exports com.sun.jmx.remote.security to jdk.management.agent, java.management.rmi;
    exports sun.management to jdk.management, jdk.management.agent, jdk.jconsole;
    exports javax.management.modelmbean;
    exports com.sun.jmx.remote.internal to jdk.management.agent, java.management.rmi;
    exports java.lang.management;
    exports sun.management.counter.perf to jdk.management.agent;
    exports javax.management;
    exports javax.management.relation;
    exports sun.management.spi to jdk.management;
    exports javax.management.openmbean;
    exports javax.management.monitor;
    exports javax.management.loading;

    uses javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorProvider;
    uses javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorServerProvider;
    uses sun.management.spi.PlatformMBeanProvider;

    provides javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule with com.sun.jmx.remote.security.FileLoginModule;
}
```

and

```
module java.management.rmi {
    requires transitive java.management;
    requires transitive java.rmi;
    requires java.naming;

    exports javax.management.remote.rmi;
    exports com.sun.jmx.remote.protocol.rmi to java.management;
    exports com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.rmi to jdk.management.agent;

    provides javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorServerProvider with com.sun.jmx.remote.protocol.rmi.ServerProvider;
    provides javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorProvider with com.sun.jmx.remote.protocol.rmi.ClientProvider;
}
```